# LTSpice Solar / photovoltaic simulation

Tags: solar-cell, ltspice

I've been trying to simulate a solar cell with LTSpice to generate an I-V curve. The model I've been using is the simplified equivalent circuit model with a current source in parallel with a diode. See image from NI:

[image]

The problem is that I can't find what kind of values the components should have.

I'm using an IKEA PV module from the Sunnan lamp and I want to have a simulation of this to show the curve compared to measured. There is unfortunately no information on the module, but I have measured 1.64V open circuit indoor and about 260µA short circuit. Is there a way to base the simulation on that information?

Comment: The open circuit voltage is NOT from Ie across Rsh!. It is from Ie through that diode. You module probably has four or so cells in series. To make things simple, put four diodes in series there, and mess with the ideality parameters of the diode to get your voltage. Rs in an amorphous cell is pretty high, I think, very nearly Voc / Ie.

Comment: @BobbiBennett - I've deleted my comment Bobbi - I've been wracking my brain as to why I didn't see the diode when I commented and I can't figure it!!?!

Comment: I spent a long time trying to find a typical diode equation for amorphous cells, too; no luck. Is that really 260uA? Guess so. Maybe that Sunnan really has 7 cells in the string?? Anyway, mess with Is in the diode equation, not ideality factor.